# Do I need UAE Visa for Hanoi, Vietnam to Dubai to Alamaty, Kazaksthan

Tags: transit-visas, dubai, uae, vietnam, flydubai

I am traveling from Vietnam to Kazakhstan. I am looking to buy these flight tickets separately.

First Hanoi-Dubai (DXB T1) in Philippines Airlines
4 Hours Layover.
2nd Dubai (DXB T3) - Alamaty, Kazakhstan via Fly Dubai.

I am buying these tickets separately. Will I need transit visa for this time or I don't need transit visa to travel to terminal 3 from terminal 1?

I am a Bangladeshi Passport Holder, I will don't have any checked baggage. I will carry only backpack.

Comment: What is your nationality, and are you planning to take checked baggage?

Comment: I am from Bangladesh, Bangladeshi Passport Holder. And I will take hand baggage no checked baggage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had booked my Han-DXB ticket with Philipens Airlines, They are partnered airline of Fly Dubai. So they give me my boarding pass from Hanoi and I didn't need any visa for Dubai to Alamaty flight.